# Filtering form design

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Assuming I have a blog with entries i would like to filter optionally by category or date: For the filter I use the following form

```
#forms.py

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Category.objects.all(),
                                                required=False)
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

I ve got the following view:

```
#views.py

blog_entries = Blog.objects.all()
cat_filter = TurnoverFilterForm(request.GET)
    if cat_filter.is_valid():
        categories_chosen = cat_filter.cleaned_data['categories']
        start_date = cat_filter.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = cat_filter.cleaned_data['end_date']
        blog_entries = blog_entries.cat_filter(categories_chosen).date_filter(start_date,end_date)
return render(request,'index.html',{'blog_entries':blog_entries}
```

Where `date_filter` and `cat_filter` are customized manager functions (which work).

The questions are:

1. Do I really need to make each field in form optional? Is there any optional form for those cases? (since there is a lot of code redundancy)
2. i ve got an ugly if-statement in my form since the form is always valid (or at least should be as category and date range is optional and the form's request type is 'get'
3. Is there any other elegant solution for this sort of problems? I can imagine it is really common

Comment: The form is most certainly not always valid. What if I send you a request with a category that isn't one of your given ones, or a date that isn't formatted as a date?

Comment: Both is caught by `date_filter` and `cat_filter`

Comment: I don't understand point number 2. I don't see the ugly `if`. Is it the one in the `views.py`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the fields in the form to be optional you may override the `__init__` function of the form like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for f in self.fields:
        self.fields[f].required=False
```

That way you set all the fields' required field to False and avoid code redundancy to make the whole form become optional.

Like `is_valid` method will return `True` always you may remove it from your code and add to the form another function which encapsulate the remaining code in the `views.py`.

With this you may simplify a little bit that code. If you want something fancier think about subclass the Form class and create `OptionalForm` so you can make that code reusable.

Comment: I cannot remove the `is_valid` method in that case because otherwise my form does not have `cleaned_data` . What I am very interested it: Is this the common way of performing this sort of tasks? I can imagine that one has this sort of problems more often ;)

Comment: Well, I am not an institution in Django's best practices but I think despite it's a quite large framework it doesn't have a class for every single possible purpose of its end users. As with all frameworks, sometimes comes to the developer to do some kind of clever coding in order to get beautiful and useful solutions :) PS: You're right about the `is_valid` but still, you may just call it without the `if` :P